# How to Calculate. It's Hard to calculate count(*) of table with existing Sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a form which have stars for rating from 1-5
i have count each user hits over individual value
Now i need to have count(*) of my table along with my result
i have achieved this with sub-query but for me cost of query matters that's why i am tired
to calculate count(*) along with my existing query.
How to add a column with existing record which calculate count of all records in table.?
I will attach my output

```
    WITH survey AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                student_id,
                performance,
                teacher_behaviour,
                syllabus,
                survey_id
            FROM
                survey_feedback
            WHERE
                survey_id = 1
            GROUP BY
                student_id,
                performance,
                teacher_behaviour,
                syllabus,
                survey_id
        ) UNPIVOT ( star
            FOR q
        IN ( performance AS 'PERFORMANCE',
             teacher_behaviour AS 'TEACHER_BEHAVIOUR',
             syllabus AS 'SYLLABUS' ) )
    ORDER BY
        1,
        2
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    survey PIVOT (
        COUNT ( student_id )
        FOR star
        IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
    )
ORDER BY
    q;


Output is

1   PERFORMANCE         0   1   2   2   1
1   SYLLABUS            2   2   2   0   0
1   TEACHER_BEHAVIOUR   2   0   1   1   2

Desired Output is

1   PERFORMANCE         0   1   2   2   1  6 <-Want this total count of table 
1   SYLLABUS            2   2   2   0   0  6
1   TEACHER_BEHAVIOUR   2   0   1   1   2  6
```

Comment: Please see the section [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. In this case you are missing table definitions, DDL, sample data. And since you mention performance (cost) include explain plan and indexes.

Comment: @Belayer nobody can answer this i have asked same question with many peoples everything is clear desired output picture is mentioned i just need count(*) of table record count with existing record

Comment: Everything is not clear. You haven't shown the raw data for the result you get now, or the result you want to get. Please edit your question to include at least those, and preferably the table definition.

Comment: @AlexPoole inside the code in last i have attached result.

Comment: Output is

1   PERFORMANCE               0   1   2   2   1  6  <---i want this count(*) 6 is total record 
1   SYLLABUS                        2   2   2   0   0  6
1   TEACHER_BEHAVIOUR   2   0  1   1   2  6

Comment: @AlexPoole now see code section i have mentioned my desire output.Thanks